# Python: Count (x, y) points in a unit circle and sum to estimate pi

Tags: python, random, python-3.5, pi

Beginner in python here.

300 points are randomly generated where x and y are between 0 and 1.

I need to count the number of points that are generated inside the unit circle and to also estimate pi using these points. I typically want the code to be similar to this (what I have so far):

```
import math
import random

points = 300
x = [random.random() for jj in range(points)]
y = [random.random() for xx in x]
count = 0

for xx, yy in zip(x,y) :
    if xx**2 + yy**2 < 1:
       do_not_count_it
    else:
       count_it
sum = all_points_in_unit_circle
```

Any suggestions on how to complete the code?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: It's unusual to be familiar with list comprehensions and `zip` but not with how to add 1 to an integer variable.  I'd revisit the early sections of whatever your tutorial is.

Comment: It looks like you are 95% of the way there.  What are you having problems with?  Incrementing the counter?  Figuring out how incrementing the counter corresponds to calculating `pi`?

Comment: My problem is how to use the counter to calculate pi!

Answer (score 1):

You were close

1. You just need a condition when the point is inside (no need for `else:`).
2. You inverted the condition (you count when `< 1`)
3. Variables `sum` and  `count` are the same.
4. This was not a mistake, but use multiplication instead of exponentiation when possible.
5. Library math is unused.  You could have used `sqrt()`, but since `sqrt(1)==1`, it would be useless.

Which gives:

```
import random

points = 300
x = [random.random() for jj in range(points)]
y = [random.random() for xx in x]
count = 0

for xx, yy in zip(x,y) :
  if xx * xx + yy * yy < 1:
    count += 1

print (count)
```

BTW, it works for pyhton2 and python3.

Comment: How do I print the total number of points instead of printing all count values (i.e. "4" as opposed to "1,2,3,4")?

Comment: The variable `count` will contain a single number (integer), not a list of numbers. The number of points should be near 236 (300 * pi / 4).  Copy and paste the program, and try it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with [Monte Carlo](https://web.archive.org/web/20171222045939/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/51909.html) methods, but a quick read tells me that you should simply do

```
for xx, yy in zip(x,y) :
    if xx**2 + yy**2 <= 1:
        count+=1
```

And then just approximate pi like so

```
approxPi = 4.0 * count / points
```

Comment: xrange is only relevant for Python 2, no?

Comment: Of course the interesting thing is _why_ the approximation is `4 * count / number_of_points`.

Comment: Yes, the forum i linked has a concise explanation. Trying to find some more papers on this

Comment: Thanks, Humphrey. Edited it out. Though that makes this answer not worth being an answer now :D OP had it all figured out

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it like this:

```
from random import random

num_of_points = 300
points = [(random(), random()) for _ in range(num_of_points)]

points_inside = sum(x**2 + y**2 < 1 for x, y in points)
```

Answer (score -2):

Here the radius of circle is 0.5 and the area of circle is **Pi*0.5^2 = Pi*0.25**; and the square is 1x1 and the area of square is **1x1 = 1**.

The **#point_in_circle / #point_in_square = area_of_circle / area_of_square**,

so we have **circle_count / all_count = Pi*0.25 / 1**

we get **Pi = circle_count / all_count * 1 / 0.25**

This code will print out the PI value:

```
import math
import random

points = 300
x = [random.random() for jj in range(points)]
y = [random.random() for xx in x]
count_circle = 0

for xx, yy in zip(x,y) :
    if xx**2 + yy**2 <= 1:
        count_circle += 1

pi = count_circle/points/0.25
print (pi)
```